# Trying to find RegionIntersection between InfiniteLine and Polygon results in a BooleanRegion that won't evaluate

Tags: regions, polygons

So I have a set of `Polygon`s that I'm obtaining from some ImageJ measurements, and I'd like to sequentially find the intersection points of systematically placed horizontal lines with these polygons.
I'm using the following (simplified) code once the polygons have been rotated and translated to the origin.

Here are the coordinates of an example polygon:

```
{{-74.0165, 299.034}, {-71.8493, 229.211}, {-37.9741, 
  149.258}, {-33.4983, 86.2663}, {-36.5136, 35.7597}, {0., 
  0.}, {31.0483, 0.0471143}, {60.6361, 28.6926}, {69.8234, 
  87.0672}, {75.6655, 142.474}, {75.3829, 243.864}, {82.2615, 
  295.407}, {57.5737, 348.834}, {13.8516, 380.589}, {-31.6137, 
  372.533}, {-71.0012, 349.541}}
```

And a snippet of how I'm trying to extract the intersection points:

```
rods = Table[
  Polygon[wholeRodCoords[[i]]],
  {i,1,Dimensions[wholeRodCoords][[1]]}
];
il = InfiniteLine[{{0,1},{1,1}}];
intercepts = RegionIntersection[rods[[1]],il];
```

Which results in this output:

```
BooleanRegion[#1&&#2&,{Polygon[],InfiniteLine[{{0,1},{1,1}}]}]
```

but no discrete points.

If I try a toy example:

```
poly = Polygon[{{0,0},{1,4},{2,2},{3,-1}}];
line = InfiniteLine[{{1,2},{2,2}}];
RegionIntersection[poly,line]
```

I get the following expected output:

```
Line[{{1/2,2},{2,2}}]
```

So, my primary questions are these:

1. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?
2. If not, why is this behavior occurring? I'm not really able to troubleshoot why these expressions are incompatible.
3. What is a possible solution to this behavior?

Comment: try `RegionIntersection[rods[[1]], DiscretizeRegion @ il]`?

Comment: This evaluates! Though, I'm not sure how to get the intersection points from the resulting object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To get the full intersection, one way is `DiscretizeRegion` the result of `RegionIntersection`.

```
Clear[pts, poly, line, reg, inter];
pts = {{-74.0165, 299.034}, {-71.8493, 229.211}, {-37.9741, 
    149.258}, {-33.4983, 86.2663}, {-36.5136, 35.7597}, {0., 
    0.}, {31.0483, 0.0471143}, {60.6361, 28.6926}, {69.8234, 
    87.0672}, {75.6655, 142.474}, {75.3829, 243.864}, {82.2615, 
    295.407}, {57.5737, 348.834}, {13.8516, 380.589}, {-31.6137, 
    372.533}, {-71.0012, 349.541}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
line = InfiniteLine[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}}];
reg = RegionIntersection[poly, line]
inter = DiscretizeRegion@reg;
Graphics[{Brown, poly, Red, line, Green, Thick, inter}]
```

- Or calculate the intersection of the boundary of the polygon and the line for this case.

```
intersection =RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary@poly, line]
Graphics[{Brown, poly, Red, line, Green, Thick, Line@@intersection}]
```

> `Point[{{-2.04216, 2.}, {33.0654, 2.}}]`

[image]

- Test another line.

```
line = InfiniteLine[{-25, 10}, {-2, 11}];
intersection = RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary@poly, line]
Graphics[{Brown, poly, Red, line, Black, Thick, Green, 
  Line /@ Partition[intersection[[1]], 2, 2], AbsolutePointSize[5], 
  intersection}]
```

> `Point[{{-73.2888, 275.588}, {-59.6, 200.3}, {-34.8253,  64.0391}, {-28.2039, 27.6216}}]`

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I was not aware that you could call `DiscretizeRegion` on the `BooleanRegion` that doesn't evaluate. `RegionBoundary` is another extremely useful function. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pts = {{-74.0165, 299.034}, {-71.8493, 229.211}, {-37.9741, 
    149.258}, {-33.4983, 86.2663}, {-36.5136, 35.7597}, {0., 0.}, {31.0483, 
    0.0471143}, {60.6361, 28.6926}, {69.8234, 87.0672}, {75.6655, 
    142.474}, {75.3829, 243.864}, {82.2615, 295.407}, {57.5737, 
    348.834}, {13.8516, 380.589}, {-31.6137, 372.533}, {-71.0012, 349.541}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
line = InfiniteLine[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}];
```

Use [`RegionConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionConvert.html) to convert the [`BooleanRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BooleanRegion.html) to an [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

```
reg = RegionConvert[
  RegionIntersection[poly, line], "Implicit"]
```

[image]

Use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) to simplify the `ImplicitRegion`

```
intercepts = ReplacePart[reg,
  1 -> N[Reduce[reg[[1]] // Rationalize[#, 0] &]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Region[Style[poly, LightBlue]],
 Region[Style[line, LightGray, Thick, Dashed]],
 Region[Style[intercepts, Red, Thick]],
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Using the same approach with cvgmt's second example:

```
line2 = InfiniteLine[{-25, 10}, {-2, 11}];

reg2 = RegionConvert[
   RegionIntersection[poly, line2], "Implicit"];

intercepts2 = ReplacePart[reg2,
  1 -> N[Reduce[reg2[[1]] // Rationalize[#, 0] &]]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Region[Style[poly, LightBlue]],
 Region[Style[line2, LightGray, Thick, Dashed]],
 Region[Style[intercepts2, Red, Thick]],
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I think the implicit region would be more useful in certain scenarios, but I think the approach by `cvgmt` is more useful in my case. Although, now that I think about it, the `Implicit` approach is probably more performant?